# What is the difference between "weighted" and "weighed"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it better to say "weighted down" or "weighed down"? Or doesn't it matter?

Here's the sentence:

> The mortgage process today remains complex and weighted down with a huge number of documents required.

Comment: Related: [Unweighed? Why not unweighted?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385061)

Answer (score 6):

It would be better to use *weighed down* here. Weighted down is usually found in a more literal context of adding ballast, as in, "The balloon was weighted down so it wouldn't fly away". Weighed down is appropriate for a more figurative context of adding something unnecessary or undesirable.

Answer (score 4):

"Weighted down" is redundant.

**Weighed down** and **weighted** (no preposition) can mean the same thing in some contexts.

***Weighed down*** can, in principle, denote some kind of burden - good or bad.

***Weighted***, on the other hand, is a purely technical term: an adverbish adjective meaning "with added weight," "with some ballast."

For instance, the keys on professional electronic pianos are typically **weighted**. They bounce back slower than ordinary plastic keys in order to imitate the "real" piano key action. There are fully-weighted and semi-weighted versions.

[image]